# Visual Studio Cordova Java Version Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

[image]

What I did I could not get rid of this error. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: For each error there is a error-description in that list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `JAVA_HOME` to `JRE` folder, you need to set  it to your `JDK` folder. Generally, the `JDK` folder is under the same root folder of `JRE`:

[image]

To change the folder path of `JAVA_HOME`, you can change the value of `JAVA_HOME` under `VS->Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Environment Variable Overrides`.